# On Android, a file keeps uploading even though deleted

Tags: android, upload

I've initiated a photo upload to a server using apache's FileEntity API. I've deleted the photo - while the upload was still running.

What I'm seeing is that the upload continues as if the file is still there. I've checked with a file browsing app and the file indeed wasn't there.

Trying the same with Dropbox gave the same result - dropbox keeps uploading the file, even though it was deleted.

**Can someone explain this behavior?**

Comment: First stop the process that is uploading the file when ever file delete event is done  means stops that thread or task that is uploading the file .

Comment: Hi @GOLDEE, the file is being deleted by another app, like the gallery. Do you mean I should listen to filesystem changes?

Comment: yeah you may listen that changes or you can first make a copy for your self and then transfer that file so that if your file is deleted from other app , you can still able to transfer that file ;)